# Line intersection - with a difference (excel VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, geometry, trigonometry, intersection

I have been working on a problem and through all of my research I have been unable to find an existing resolution. I do not have the required math knowledge to produce an elegant solution.

There are several examples of working (and very elegant) line - line intersections with either complete lines or line segment (see links) :

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/99937114/Forums/Eileens%20Lounge%20-%20LinearIntersect_Corrected.xls

(other examples in the dropbox shared folder)

The problem I have is illustrated using the attached image. There is a defined line, starting at L1 (x,y) and finishing at L2 (x,y). There is no second line - instead there are the coordinates for another point (effectively L3) and an axis or angle of travel. I need to calculate the distance to and coordinates of the intersect if the point L3 was continued along the axis / angle of travel.

[image: Illustration]

It would also be useful to get the coordinates of a position when provided with an origin, a bearing and a distance e.g. x, y with a distance of 10m on a bearing of 195 degrees arrives you at x, y? This is effectively the same function, except the distance is defines vs calculating the distance and x, y of the intersection

Comment: Redacted sample data together with the expected results would have gone a long way towards making this an excellent question. If sample data has to be randomly generated in order to proof a solution, how can we be sure that the data is relevant to your situation?

Comment: Apologies. The data is very simple e.g. line 1 comprised of L1 (x,y) coordinates and L2 (x,y) coordinates. Then the distant position L3 (x,y) coordinates which has a bearing and a distance. After researching it more it would appear that the line L1 to L2 should instead be converted into a vector and then used to intersect the vector from L3 using the bearing?

Comment: I would look at this as a Euclidian Geometry proof. Getting the hypotenuse from L¹ to P¹ is a simple matter. Getting the opposite angle formed at the imaginary intersect is another SOHCAHTOA problem. After that everything is ASA (angle-side-angle) and the Law of Sines with some addition and subtraction thrown in. However, without sample data together with the expected results (and some original effort) I may simply be going off on a tangent trying to provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Coming from a background of projective geometry, computing cross products of homogeneous coordinates is my favorite way to elegantly join points or intersect (infinite) lines. In your case, I'd first rename points. Suppose the first line is defined by `A` and `B`, and the second line passes through `C` and has angle `z` as you indicated. Then I'd compute

```
⎡Dx⎤   ⎛⎡Ax⎤   ⎡Bx⎤⎞   ⎛⎡Cx⎤   ⎡sin z⎤⎞   ⎡(Ay Bx - Ax By) sin z - (Cx cos z - Cy sin z) (Ax - Bx)⎤
⎢Dy⎥ = ⎜⎢Ay⎥ × ⎢By⎥⎟ × ⎜⎢Cy⎥ × ⎢cos z⎥⎟ = ⎢(Ay Bx - Ax By) cos z - (Cx cos z - Cy sin z) (Ay - By)⎥
⎣Dz⎦   ⎝⎣1 ⎦   ⎣1 ⎦⎠   ⎝⎣1 ⎦   ⎣  0  ⎦⎠   ⎣(Ay    -    By) sin z - (Ax       - Bx      ) cos z    ⎦
```

Then `(Dx/Dz, Dy/Dz)` are the coordinates of the point of intersection, and the distance from that to `C` can be computed in the usual way using Pythagoras. The first inner cross product describes the line joining `A` and `B`. The second inner cross product joins `C` with a point at infinity in the direction you indicated. The outer cross product then intersects these two lines, yielding homogeneous coordinates for the point of intersection.

Comment: How would I implement this in excel or VBA. This is the main barrier - the math is there, but I do not have a practical solution. My math knowledge is lacking in this area...

Comment: @user3076007: It's been ages since I did any VBA programming, but if you take the expanded form to the right of my formula, then all you have to do is call sin and cos and then perform elementary arithmetic operations: subtractions, multiplications, divisions. Of course it might be more elegant if you write your own little subroutine for the cross product, and implement stuff on that high level. I'm not going to write VBA code for you.